# Perforce Web App

Tags: perforce

I'm building a web app which is located on the same server as Perforce.
The web app needs to act as a sort of GUI for simple Perforce operations, e.g. sync, check out.
I have 2 approaches in mind:

1. Run p4web service on each client, and have the web app communicate with this  to execute p4 commands, as per the following:

   > **Embedding P4 Commands in URLs**
   >
   > You can execute p4 commands by embedding them in URLs. Command results
   >   are displayed by your browser as text. (This feature is notably useful
   >   for Java applications.)
   >
   > To embed commands in URLs, use the following format::
   >
   > http://[webhost:port]/p4 command [cmdflags] [args]?ac=160 (or ac=161
   >   for tagged output)
   >
   > **Example:** http://localhost:8080/p4 client -d oldclient?ac=160

   http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/p4web/help/commands.html
2. Have the web app run perforce commands (p4) directly on the server to perform actions on the client, e.g. sync files

If it is possible, I would prefer #2 as it wouldn't require p4web running on the client. However, I haven't had this working yet - running commands on the server (such as >>p4 -u Username -H Username-PC -c WorkSpace sync //depot/...) appear to work on the server, but have no effect on the client files.

I had more success with #1, but only after authenticating through the P4Web login form. I need to authenticate via scripting somehow but I can't find appropriate documentation on how to.

Is there any information on how to overcome these issues, or is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: Can you arrange for some sort of networked file system so that the server can directly access the client workspace directory trees? For example, can all your client workspaces locate their folders on a single NFS server? This could allow your web app to operate on the client files. Beware, though: centralizing all this work onto a single machine might make your web app a bottleneck and it could easily become overloaded.

Comment: Could you use the P4 JavaScript API? See http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4jsapi/aa_p4.html#1043831. Then you'd be executing on the client, at least?

Comment: As I think you understand, the sync command requires the app to have access to the filesystem where the files are to be synced - thus your client machine, or as Bryan suggests, a shared filesystem visible to both.

As an aside, P4Web is now open source: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4web/files/main

Should be possible to tweak it for authentication.

Comment: So an instance of p4 running on the server and one on the client can't communicate to achieve this? I will look into a shared filesystem option but I don't think it'll work.